# Piggyback to Ubuntu Touch application

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have made an application that I would like to run as a piggyback to another application on my phone Aquarius E 4.5 Ubuntu Edition. I tried to add my app to:

```
cd .local/share/applications
vi navigator.costales_navigator_0.62.desktop
```

---

```
Exec=aa-exec-click -p navigator.costales_navigator_0.62 -- qmlscene %u qml/Main.qml;my_app
```

but no, how should this be done?

/S

Answer (score 0):

When an app starts in Ubuntu Touch, Upstart will emit a specific signal. If you have a script you want to run when an app starts you can add a file in Upstart that will run when the `application-click` signal fires. For example I created a file in `~/.config/upstart/application-click-log.conf` with the contents:

```
start on started application-click 
export INSTANCE

pre-start script
/bin/bash <<EOT
    echo "$INSTANCE starting"
EOT
end script
```

You can then watch the log file (`~/.cache/upstart/application-click-log.log`) and it will print something like this:

```
com.ubuntu.terminal_terminal_0.7.198 starting
navigator.costales_navigator_0.65 starting
```

Alternatively you could replace the `Exec=...` line in the desktop file with your own script that launches the app and also does anything extra.